# Trying to figure out this code, object in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object, nested

Basically we have:

```
var nasdaqHighChart = function () {
  /*
  a bunch of functions ()
  ...
  */

  function UpdateQuoteData()  {
  }

  return {
    updateQuoteData : UpdateQuoteData
  };
}();
```

I am interested in running the last function that is nested inside of this object.
My question is what exactly is nasdaqHighChart? Because when I use `nasdaqHighChart.typeof` it says undefined. Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nasdaqHighChart` is a plain object (with one property called `updateQuoteData`), as you would have seen by running `typeof nasdaqHighChart`.

`typeof` isn't a property of object but an operator. [See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

The construct you see is called [an IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), the main purpose is to allow the definition of "a bunch of functions" and properties without pollution of the external scope.

Comment: Thank you, what is the most efficient way to execute the nested functions inside of nsh?

Comment: @JoeCurcuru You can't execute those function from the external scope if they're not externalized (like is for example the `updateQuoteData` function).

Comment: Thanks this pretty much answers my question.